# How Chrome calculate transparency color?

Tags: google-chrome, opacity, alpha-transparency

I've been trying to understand how Chrome calculate transparency color in whole day. And also I've seen same  linear interpolation `alpha * forground_color + (1 - alpha) * background_color` formula thousand times on the internet. It works if background was white. But if background is not white Chrome gives me different resulting values...
For example:

```css
.bg {
  background-color: #666; /* or rgb(102, 102, 102) */
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.fg {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .87);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="fg"></div>
</div>
```

Expecting value was `rgb(235, 13, 13)` but Chrome gives me `rgb(236, 31, 27)`.
Even though background is gray and foreground green and blue components are 0 resulting value is `rgb(236, 31, 27)`. How come resulting value's green and blue components are different from each other? And itsn't even close resulting value `102 * (1 - .87) = 102 * .13 = 13.26`. I tried many other color combinations. Chrome doesn't linearly blending colors if background is not white. Can you tell me how Chrome calculate transparency color?

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the values of color inside your square and it seems that everything works correctly. I guess that you have some extra colors in your project or you have some kind of chrome plugin that changes colors e.g. Dark Reader.

[image]

```
bg-color = rgb(102, 102, 102)
fg-color = rgba(255, 0, 0, .87)

calculations: 
Red: 0.87 * 255 + (0.13) * 102 = 235.11
Green: 0.87 * 0 + (0.13) * 102 = 13.26
Blue: 0.87 * 0 + (0.13) * 102 = 13.26

result:
rgb(235, 13, 13)
```

Comment: No, it doesn't on my computer. By the way what is your OS? I have MacOS Big Sur and Chrome Version 88.0.4324.182 (Official Build) (x86_64). Also it works as expected on Firefox. But Chrome doesn't interpolate linearly.

Comment: MacOS Big Sur 11.0.1 (20B50)
Chrome Version 88.0.4324.96 (Official Build) (x86_64)

Does it happen also in chrome incognito mode?

Comment: Yes, it still resulting value `rgb(236, 31, 27)` in incognito mode too.